# Overture and Mathematical Syntax

Tags: vdm++

Is it possible to use the VDM mathematical syntax with Overture or is it restricted to the ASCII syntax.

Alternatively, when generating LaTeX, can the mathematical syntax be used for the output?

I have barely used LaTeX. I tried taking the output '.tex' and replacing 'forall' with '\forall' in the TeX file, then regenerated the PDF, but that just inserted '\forall' in the PDF. I tired with '$\forall$' with the same result.

By the way, VDM and Overture in combination make for a fantastic environment in which to create specifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas no, neither Overture nor VDMJ can use the mathematical notation. I believe VDMTools can though (its pretty printing), but it would be quite annoying to switch between the two just for that. It would be relatively easy to add to Overture, but perhaps of limited use? One of the things I've found over the years is that the mathematical notation is quite off-putting to beginners.

The link below summarizes the differences between Overture and VDMTools, and mentions the pretty printer:
http://wiki.overturetool.org/index.php/Differences_between_Overture_and_VDMTools

We're very pleased to hear you find Overture useful. If you have any problems or suggestions, do get in touch and we'll try to help - http://overturetool.org/.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt responses to my questions Nick. I take your point about the mathematical syntax being off-putting for beginners. With experience of mathematical notation I find the conciseness and judicious use of symbols to be a great aid in understanding a specification. If my vague plans come to fruition I may end up introducing this to others at which point the ASCII syntax may well pay dividends - it looks more like a Java program!

Comment: People will eventually get used to any notation, but we have to remove barriers for beginners if possible. Another aspect is that the editors that are used to enter specifications work easily in ASCII (ie. with a qwerty keyboard), so the mathematical notation tends to be "output only". Schemes for inputting mathematical symbols (with CTRL character etc) are possible, but cumbersome, which then becomes yet another barrier.